# Ordering axes and making data more presentable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to order the time and date axes on my scatter plot into epochs/ time periods. For example, times between 12pm-:7:59pm and 9pm-11:59pm. I want to do something similar for the dates.

I am fairly new to R so I am just looking for suggestions/ to be told if this is even possible and maybe some alternatives:)

This is my code so far:

```
accident <- read.csv("accidents.csv",header = TRUE)
accident <- accident %>%
ggplot(data=accident)+
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=Time, y=Date, alpha=0.5))
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to R! Here is one set of options.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

#### First, simulate dataset

```r
accident <- 
  rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 1500000000, sd = 1000000) %>% 
  tibble(date_time = .) %>% 
  mutate(date_time = as.POSIXct(date_time, origin = "1970-01-01")) %>% 
  separate(date_time, into = c("date", "time"), sep = " ", remove = F)
```

#### Original plot:

```r
accident %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x=time, y=date), alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

#### Step 1: Collapse the x axis into smaller number of groups

```r
accidents_per_trihour <- 
  accident %>%
  mutate(hour = floor_date(date_time, unit = "hour"), 
         hour = as.numeric(str_sub(hour, 12,13)), 
         tri_hour = cut(hour, c(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24), include.lowest = T)) %>% 
  group_by(date, tri_hour) %>% 
  count()
```

Then scale dot size by number of accidents

```r
accidents_per_trihour %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x=tri_hour, y=date, size = n), alpha=0.5) + 
  labs(x = "\nTime (in three-hour groups)", y = "Day\n", size = "Accidents count")
```

[image]

Still not great because the y axis is too expansive. So:

#### Step 2: Collapse the y axis into smaller number of groups

(For your data you may need to group into months for things to start to look reasonable)

```r
accidents_per_trihour_per_week <- 
  accident %>%
  mutate(hour = floor_date(date_time, unit = "hour"), 
         hour = as.numeric(str_sub(hour, 12,13)), 
         tri_hour = cut(hour, c(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24), include.lowest = T)) %>% 
  mutate(week_start = floor_date(as.Date(date), unit = "weeks"), 
         week = format.Date(week_start, "%Y, week %W"))  %>% 
  group_by(week, tri_hour) %>% 
  count()
```

Should be much more readable now
We’ll improve the theme as well, just because.

```r
if (!require(ggthemr)) devtools::install_github('cttobin/ggthemr')
ggthemr::ggthemr("flat") ## helps with pretty theming

accidents_per_trihour_per_week %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x=tri_hour, y=week, size = n), alpha = 0.9) + 
  labs(x = "\nTime (in three-hour groups)", y = "Week\n", size = "Accidents count")
```

[image]

Could also do a tile plot

```r
accidents_per_trihour_per_week %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x = tri_hour, y = week, fill = n)) + 
  geom_label(aes(x = tri_hour, y = week, label = n), alpha = 0.4, size = 2.5, fontface = "bold") +
  labs(x = "\nTime (in three-hour groups)", y = "Week\n", fill = "Accidents count")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Wow thank you for that! This was far beyond the response I was expecting haha. If you don't mind my last question is I'm working with 129,983 rows of data from an excel file about road accidents in the UK (I'm reading this from a csv.file). How would I go about using these records instead of the predefined dates you set? I'm guessing this would be done in accident <- under rnorm() somewhere.

Comment: Just skip the whole "simulate dataset" part and go straight to plotting. I see your variables are capitalized though. In my reprex, the column names are all lower case. Pay attention to that.